# dante SOCKS5 server handle authentication with external script

Tags: authentication, socks, dante

I'm currently choosing between using dante or 3proxy for creating a SOCKS5 server.

My user login details are stored in a mysql table. Passwords are generated using bcrypt(), so RADIUS won't be an option. Is there a way to handle the authentication process of logins with external scripts in 3proxy?

Where can I find some information about this? On the website I don't see informations regarding this.